# recompiled kernel with luks full-disk encryption?

Tags: boot, kernel, encryption, luks

I need to remove xhci_hcd from my kernel.  It should be a module so that I can blacklist it.

I cloned `git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-disco.git`, and I was able to successfully run `fakeroot debian/rules binary`.  I then installed the resulting .deb files.  My grub menus were updated, the `local1` suffix was correctly added to all files and menu items, everything looks good.

I needed to modify the xhci and ehci entries in the 'annotations' file, which seems like a guardrail to be sure that no unexpected changes were made - this was reassuring.

I have full-disk encryption configured by the installer, and if I boot with my new kernel, entering my key does not unlock my disk.  Standard english keyboard layout.

I have searched google, and grepped my disk and the docs.  I am certain that it's a one-liner that I'm just missing?  Some grub or initramfs configuration that is so obvious nobody talks about it.

Any clues, any clues at all, will almost certainly help me.

Edit: To clarify, the reaction I get when I enter the passkey, is identical to the reaction I would expect if the passkey is entered incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be `make mrproper`, `make`, and `fixup lilo`.  Now I feel dumb for two days building the kernel, once. I'm still confused, but that's another cover.  In the end, here is what worked:

- uninstall the 5.0.0-29 kernel packages entirely (nevermind adding suffix to beat the versioning, I purged them all entirely, I have a previous version built by The Canonical to fallback to).
- `git reset --hard` in the repo (etc, until `git status` was clean)
- `fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs` (I hit ctrl-c after amd64-generic)
- edit `debian.master/config/annotations` to match the changes I made to .config
- `fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-perarch binary-generic`
- `dpkg -i ../*.deb`

So many bugs, but the original question above is now solved and I can handle the rest.  The only reason I use ubuntu now, is the single fact that the installer does this full-disk encryption for me.  afaik, it's the only one that does.  others?  Any others, and I'll switch.

Thanks for your patience, everyone who read this question (all 11 of ya).

I love you all.